# Arduino Micro serial port drops connection after a few seconds

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I recently purchased an Arduino Micro ATMega32u4. I was testing it out first on "Mac OSX El Capitan" and it was working fine, until I decided to test someone's code or until I updated my El Capitan security settings. I've read that when you upload a main() function that is bigger then what it can handle the board stops working until you reset the main(). So i decided to try to use arduino on my Linux machine but it drops the connection approximately around 7 seconds. I read on an old post that is a common thing with Micros and that I needed to hit the reset button and upload the blink example fast. Because that is when the port works. But as soon I hit upload it get this    error message.

```
Sketch uses 928 bytes (2%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2,039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
ioctl("TIOCMSET"): Broken pipe
ioctl("TIOCMSET"): Broken pipe
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
```

Within those first few seconds I can see the arduino under `lsusb`,
`dmesg | tail` connected successfully but after the 7 seconds dmesg | tail gives me this error message and I can no longer see it under lsusb,

```
[20720.796854] usb 3-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[20720.972844] usb 3-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[20721.148875] usb 3-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 21 using ehci-pci
[20721.220860] usb 3-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[20721.396880] usb 3-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[20721.572879] usb 3-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 22 using ehci-pci
[20721.980906] usb 3-1.3: device not accepting address 22, error -32
[20722.052911] usb 3-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 23 using ehci-pci
[20722.460927] usb 3-1.3: device not accepting address 23, error -32
[20722.461090] usb 3-1-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
```

On the Arduino IDE within the first 7 seconds I see that the serial port is /dev/ttyCOM0 after the 7 seconds it's back to /dev/ttyS0 which I can't use.

On the board it self, when plugged in tx & rx are blinking simultaneously when I hit reset it another led comes on green and sometimes blinks for 3-4 seconds and when I hit reset twice it blinks for around 7 seconds. When I hit reset on the board and click on upload the green led blinking turns off and goes the tx & rx blinking sequence. Or sometimes it stays blinking green but it gives me this error 
Arduino: 1.6.12 (Linux), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

```
Sketch uses 928 bytes (2%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2,039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
ioctl("TIOCMSET"): Broken pipe
ioctl("TIOCMSET"): Broken pipe
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x3f
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
```

Any tips or suggestions on how I can fix this? 
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any programmers (e.g. a usbtinyisp) or just a USB line?

Comment: just a usb line, but after 5 hours of research I managed to fix it. I will post my solution soon. @thrig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I had to use my linux machine because my Mac OSX running 10.11.6 El Capitan was not recognizing the arduino micro but on the Linux machine it would at least pick up signal for 7 seconds. So you have to "not have the micro plugged into a usb port. Have the arduino ide open with a simple bare minimum sketch, select the leonardo board (yes even if your using a micro). Press the reset button on your micro and hold, continue holding, and plug your board into a usb port. Continue holding the reset button and select upload the sketch. As soon as your ide window finishes compiling the sketch and begins the upload process release the reset button.

My final results: The sketch loaded and the port dropping connection got fixed, my micro was continued to be recognized by the IDE program even on El Capitan. This was caused because I uploaded a sketch that was too big the arduino micro to handle.